zsh autocompletion for parametre value
General overview
Here is my auto complexion file:
_triumphum_complete() {
_arguments \
  '(- 1 *)'{-h,--help}'[show help options]' \
  '(- 1 *)--tui[Run the game selection interface]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-r,--run}'[Run a given game and track playing time.]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-a,--about}'[Show about message.]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-d,--donate}'[Open link to give a tip.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--no-splash[Do not show splash at opening.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--list-games[Afficher la liste des jeux.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--list-licences[Afficher la liste des licences.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--list-genres[Afficher la liste des genres de jeu.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--list-platforms[Afficher la liste des genres des plateformes.]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-c,--config-file}'[Select different config file from default one.]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-g,--games}'[Select different game file from default one.]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-p,--platforms}'[Select different platform file from default one.]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-l,--licences}'[Select different licence file from default one.]' \
  '(- 1 *)'{-t,--game-genres}'[Select different game genre file from default one.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--layout[Utiliser des raccourcis dactyliques adaptés à la disposition de clavier.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--add-game[Ajouter un nouveau jeu.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--add-licence[Ajouter une nouvelle licence.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--add-genre[Ajouter un nouveau genre de jeu.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--add-platform[Ajouter une nouvelle plateforme.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--del-game[Suprimer un jeu.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--del-licence[Suprimer une licence.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--del-genre[Suprimer un genre de jeu.]' \
  '(- 1 *)--del-platform[Suprimer une plateforme.]' \
}

compdef _triumphum_complete triumphum

Its render matches the goal, as you can see:
% % triumphum -<tab>
option
--about           -a  -- Show about message.
--add-game            -- Ajouter un nouveau jeu.
--add-genre           -- Ajouter un nouveau genre de jeu.
--add-licence         -- Ajouter une nouvelle licence.
--add-platform        -- Ajouter une nouvelle plateforme.
--config-file     -c  -- Select different config file from default one.
--del-game            -- Suprimer un jeu.
--del-genre           -- Suprimer un genre de jeu.
--del-licence         -- Suprimer une licence.
--del-platform        -- Suprimer une plateforme.
--donate          -d  -- Open link to give a tip.
--game-genres     -t  -- Select different game genre file from default one.
--games           -g  -- Select different game file from default one.
--help            -h  -- show help options
--layout              -- Utiliser des raccourcis dactyliques adaptés à la disposition de clavier.
--licences        -l  -- Select different licence file from default one.
--list-games          -- Afficher la liste des jeux.
--list-genres         -- Afficher la liste des genres de jeu.
--list-licences       -- Afficher la liste des licences.
--list-platforms      -- Afficher la liste des genres des plateformes.
--no-splash           -- Do not show splash at opening.
--platforms       -p  -- Select different platform file from default one.
--run             -r  -- Run a given game and track playing time.
--tui                 -- Run the game selection interface

But, I want to add an autocompletion specifically for the --run option whitch should take only as values {"crash", "civilization", "vicecity"}.
What I did
I alredy tried to make a specific autocomplection for triumphum --run and match it separately with:
_triumphum_run_games() {
    local games=('civilization' '0ad' 'vicecity' 'crash')
    _arguments 'game' games
}
compdef _triumphum_run_games "triumphum --run"   

But it doesn’t work.
The question
How to add an autocomplexion specificaly for triumphum --run ?

_arguments describes how to complete a command and its arguments. For arguments that are options that themselves take an argument, pass an option like --my-option:description of the argument:how to complete the argument. There are several ways to specify how to complete the argument of an option. To complete one of a fixed set of words, put the words in parentheses.
_arguments \
  …
  '(- 1 *)'{-r,--run}'[Run a given game and track playing time.]:game to run:(civilization 0ad vicecity crash)' \
  …

If you don't want to hard-code the completions, put code to generate the completions after the second colon. For example:
function _triumphum_run_games {
  local games
  games=("${(f@)$(_call_program triumphum-list-games ${(q)words[1]} --list-games)}")
  compadd -- $games
}
…

_arguments \
  …
  '(- 1 *)'{-r,--run}'[Run a given game and track playing time.]:game to run:_triumphum_run_games' \
  …


